# Interesting related rates question

Tags: calculus

A circle *C* in the *xy*-plane is described as follows: A point *P* on the circumference of *C* traces out the graph of $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$; the center of *C* is the *y*-intercept of the tangent line of $f(x)$ at *P*. If the center of *C* moves upwards along the *y*-axis at the rate of $\frac14$ centimeters per second, how fast is the area of *C* increasing when the center of the *C* is (0, 1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation for the tangent line at $(x_0,\sqrt x_0)$ is

$$y=\frac{1}{2\sqrt x_0}x+\frac{\sqrt x_0}{2}$$

The distance between $(0,\frac{\sqrt x_0}{2})$ and $(x_0,\sqrt x_0)$ is the radius of the circle, and this is $\sqrt{x_0^2+\frac{x_0}{4}}$.  This gives the area of the circle:

$$A(x_0)=\pi\left( x_0^2+\frac{x_0}{4}\right)$$

To put this in terms of the coordinate of the center of the circle, use $y=\frac{\sqrt x_0}{2}$:

$$A(y)=\pi\left(16y^4+y^2\right)$$

Deriving this expression and plugging in values gives:

$$\frac{dA}{dt}=\pi(16+\frac{1}{2})=\frac{33\pi}{2}$$

Comment: Solving this problem showed me something I hadn't noticed before: the y-intercept of the tangent line of $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ at the point (${x}$, $f(x)$) is $\frac12$$f(x)$, and the x-intercept is -${x}$. Thought that was interesting!